# Finding the horizontal asymptotes of $f$

Tags: calculus

The question I must answer is:

"Find the horizontal asymptotes of $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{10 x^2+11}}{12 x+10}$."

However, I am unsure how to find the horizontal asymptote or what this means. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You are asked to compute $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} \frac{\sqrt{10 x^2+11}}{12 x+10}.$ If you get two values, say $a,b,$ then $y=a$ and $y=b$ are the horizontal asymptotes. If you get only one value, say $a,$ then $y=a$ is the only horizontal asymptote.

Comment: But how do you get the two values for a and b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $y=h$ is a horizontal asymptote of any function $\phi(x)$ if and only if $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty} \phi(x)$ exists and is equal to $h$. Hence you need to compute $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{\sqrt{10x^2+11}}{12x+10}. $$ Can you see how and why it is helpful to use $10x^2+11=x^2(10+11/{x^2})$ and $12x+10=x(12+10/x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Square it.Highest degree coefficients are noted to be  $ 10, 144 $

So,it tends asymptotically to

$$ \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{ 12}.$$

Comment: Not when $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: I gave an indication, it always goes with  sqrt in the problem itself!

Comment: Uh, that's a different story.